# Remove a character from the middle of a string with regex

Tags: regex, google-chrome

I have no programing experience and thought this would be simple, but I have searched for days without luck. I am using a program to strip content from a web page. The program uses regex filters to display what you want from the stripped content. The stripped content can be any letter and is in the form of USD/SEK. I want to display USDSEK, without the "/" 
Thanks

To elaborate further - I am using a program called Data toolbar for chrome, which makes it easy to strip content from web pages. After it strips the content, it provides a regex filter to display what part of the content is displayed. But I have to know the regex command to remove the / from USD/SEK, to display just USDSEK. I've tried [A-Z.,]+ but that only displays USD. I need the regex command to grab the first 3 and last 3 characters only, or to omit the / from the string.

Comment: What programming language? You probably don't need a regex at all.

Comment: So you have `USD/SEK` and you want to display `USDSEK`, why not just remove the character?

Comment: I am using a program called Data toolbar for chrome, which makes it easy to strip content from web pages. After it strips the content, it provides a regex filter to display what part of the content is displayed. But I have to know the regex command to remove the / from USD/SEK, to display just USDSEK. I've tried [A-Z.,]+ but that only displays USD. I need the regex command to grab the first 3 and last 3 characters only, or to omit the / from the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding parentheses around the groups which you wish to capture:

```
([a-zA-Z]{3})\/([a-zA-Z]{3})
```

or

```
([a-zA-Z]{3})\/((?1))
```

Depending on the functionality of the program you are using you can then reference these captured groups as `$1`and `$2` (or `\1`and `\2` depending on flavor)